# Are app files unique to installations

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm planning on having a generated file be stored in the App/Documents file for my app. I want this file to be unique across installations so that if a user has an iPad and an iPhone they will have two different versions of the file.
I've been reading the specification(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) and am particularly concerned about this line.

> Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user-generated content.
>   The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

My question is will the files be backed up to the users account in the cloud?

Comment: What do you mean user account? Do you mean iCloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is. The Documents Directory is a key location in an app. which means that if you put anything in the documents, it will back up to itunes(if the user wants to). so even if you generated a unique file across installations, it will re-download the EXACT file to a new system if they downloaded it previously. so unique files in the DOCUMENTS will not be possible (unless a person uses a diffrent apple account on every one of his devices. which is not likely.)